# Python Run multiple subprocesses with live, overwriting output

Tags: python, windows-10, subprocess, python-3.7, popen

Under Windows 10 with Python 3.7.9, I am using Python's `subprocess.Popen` to spawn multiple subprocesses. Each of those outputs an overwriting, live output that looks like this :

```
C:\Users\Me\MyFolder>my_command.exe
[>          ] 0%
```

Then like this

```
C:\Users\Me\MyFolder>my_command.exe
[=====>     ] 50%
```

Then finally like this

```
C:\Users\Me\MyFolder>my_command.exe
[==========>] 100%
my_command finished !

C:\Users\Me\MyFolder>
```

How can I spawn multiple subprocesses in Python, each calling `my_command` and all outputting their stuff to a given line, updating the whole line live ?

Like this :

```
C:\Users\Me\MyFolder>python call_multiple_times_my_command.py
Sub0 : [>          ] 0%
Sub1 : [==========>] 100% my_command finished !
Sub2 : [=====>     ] 50%
```

We can agree that newlines will be replaced by space, so that the output of any given subprocess will never be more than one line.

My code currently looks like this :

```
import subprocess

processes = []
for i in range(0,3,1):
    processes.append(subprocess.Popen("my_command.exe", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False))

for process in processes:
    print(process)
    stdout, sterr = process.communicate()
    print(stdout)

But what I see when printing `std_out` is a garbled mix of all outputs of all subprocesses.

I found the `blessings` library but it requires `curses` which seems to only be available in later Python versions.
```